# Submitting Form with Jquery submitting Get instead Post

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

I am using WebGrid in My MVC application , for paging I am using this code

```
  var links = $('a[href*=page], a[href*=sort]');
        form = $('form')[0];
        links.click(function () {
            debugger;
            form.attr("action", this.href);
            $(this).attr("href", "javascript:");
            form.submit();
        });

@using (Html.BeginForm(Model.PostToAction, "Leads", FormMethod.Post))
```

when  form.submit() is executed it is Executed as GET and not POST ,

what am I doing wrong ?

UPDATE:

My form is :

```
<form action="/Leads/DetailsLeads" method="post">
```

Controller is :

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult DetailsLeads(LeadDetailsViewModel model)
```

Comment: could you try this: `form.attr("method","post");`

Comment: Have you read the rendered HTML to verify that it is being created as a "post" form method?  Could you paste the controller declaration(s)?  Also, just so I am clear, are you changing the action URL to the respective clicked link's href?

Comment: Try adding e.preventDefault() inside of your links.click(function(){} block.  The browser may still be trying to follow the link you clicked (GET request)

Comment: @Tommy: You should submit that as a viable answer.

Comment: @JoelEtherton - thanks, I did.  I was in a hurry when I first came across this (was actually looking for an answer to something I was working on)!

Comment: Tommy , Thanks it Helped ! Convert your cooment into answer please , I think it is very usefull !

Comment: The problem was in some code before submit , and since there were no e.PreventDefaults error couldn't be seen !!! Thanks

Comment: @StringBuilder - glad to help!  comment has been posted as an answer :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding `e.preventDefault()` inside of your `links.click(function(){}` block.  Without this, the browser will still attempt to do the action you instructed it to do (a GET request on the clicked link).

```
var links = $('a[href*=page], a[href*=sort]');
        form = $('form')[0];
        links.click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            debugger;
            form.attr("action", this.href);
            $(this).attr("href", "javascript:");
            form.submit();
        });
```

Comment: I'm being battling with this error this all morning lol. Thanks a lot.